# Error "pbjs: command not found" in run compile protobuf js with yarn

Tags: reactjs, protobufjs

I update `protobufjs` from `6.11.2` to `7.1.2` then when I run my compiler to compile my protobufs I got this error `pbjs: command not found error Command failed with exit code 127.` What shall I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to add `pbjs` globally and it resolved.
`yarn global add pbjs`